# C# : "Override or Make new DocumentCompleted Task for WebBrowser Component"

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

When you have already at one point set up a `DocumentCompleted` event like this in your code for your `WebBrowser` component:

```
br.DocumentCompleted += LoginDocument;
```

and there comes a point in your code where you need to navigate to a different website. Is it then possible to change the DocumentCompleted task either by overriding the current one or replace it with a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove this listener and add a new one

```
br.DocumentCompleted -= LoginDocument;
br.DocumentCompleted += NewDocumentCompletedHandler;
```

Comment: Okay a trivial question i see now but thanks  for the reply :)